# Install sitecore package through code to all targets

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I've figured out how to install a package via codebehind (given that I have a zip file). As I understand it, it only installs it on the master DB. How do I then get the installed items over to the web DB? Cna I Install the package on the web DB? Is there someway to get the items in the installation process, and then somehow publish them? What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you know the exact root item of where you installed items in the master, your best bet it to publish the entire tree via C# from `master` to `web`

Section 2.2.2 of the Content API Cookbook ([PDF link](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/content_api_cookbook-a4.pdf)) has this snippet of how to do that:

```
var master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");
var target = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
Sitecore.Data.Database[] targetDatabases = { target };
var languages = master.Languages;
Sitecore.Publishing.PublishManager.PublishIncremental(master, targetDatabases, languages);
```

Comment: Hmmm... the problem is, I don't neccesarily want the entire tree to go - I only want the items that the package has to go to web. Is there a way I can get the items that the package 'just' installed?

Answer (score 3):

When you create the package, you select items from specific databases.
By default this is the master, but you can also select them from core and web.

**Items will always be installed in the same database as where they came from.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try an approach like this. Since you already install the package from codebehind, you could get a list of modified items since the time the package install started and publish them.

```
Item rootItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.RootPath);
List<Item> modifiedItemList = rootItem.Axes.GetDescendants().
       Where(item => item.Statistics.Updated >= installDateTime 
             || item.Statistics.Created >= installDateTime).ToList();
// add te items in the list to the publishing queue
```

This solution is a bit dirty, but should solve your problem.